# Javascript variable reverting to original

Tags: javascript

```
function loadAll() {
    var zip64;
    var zipURL = 'settings/Images.zip';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', zipURL, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var responseArray = new Uint8Array(this.response);
            var d = responseArray.length;
            var binaryString = new Array(d);

            while (d--) {
                binaryString[d] = String.fromCharCode(responseArray[d]);
            }

            var data = binaryString.join("");
            zip64 = window.btoa(data);

            zip.createReader(new zip.Data64URIReader(zip64), function(reader) {
                reader.getEntries(function(entries) {
                    z = 0;
                    zloopid = setInterval(function() {
                        if (z >= entries.length || !entries[z]) {
                            clearInterval(zloopid);
                            reader.close();
                            start();
                            return;
                        }

                        if (entries[z].filename.split("/")[0] == "__MACOSX") {
                            z++;
                            return;
                        }

                        $("#loadimg").html("Loading " + entries[z].filename + ".... (" + (z + 1) + " of " + entries.length + ")");

                        var isMask = (entries[z].filename.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '') == "mask.jpg");

                        entries[z].getData(new zip.Data64URIWriter(), function(uri) {
                            if (isMask) {
                                imgtemp = new Image();
                                imgtemp.src = uri;
                            }
                            else {
                                var lol = new Image();
                                lol.src = uri;
                                imageLibrary.push(lol);
                            }
                        });

                        z++;
                    }, 0);
                });
            }, function(error) {
                window.location = "error.html?err=Error by unzipper: " + error + " (Problem in Images.zip)";
            });
        }
        else {
            window.location = "error.html?err=Error while retrieving zip file (" + zipURL + ") : " + this.status;
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

function start() {
    var image = imgtemp;
    width = image.width;
    height = image.height;
```

So I have this piece of code. I have a global variable named `imgtemp` but everytime I set it in the `if (inMask)` block, it reverts to undefined when `start()` is called. Why is this?

loadAll() is called first, then start(). I can confirm that when the code that calls start() in loadAll() executes, imgtemp already turned back to undefined.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to share when is `start` called and when is `loadAll` called. I mean events... Plus you have to check if there is something else that is calling some other function to make it undefined...

Comment: Have you placed a `debugger;` keyword in the function and tried to debug using Developer Toolbar

Comment: try putting a `debugger;` keyword at the beginning of the `loadAll` and `start` and see how many times each function is called...

Comment: start() is being called before imgtemp is being set in loadall()

Comment: where is your `if (inMask)` block ?

Comment: @user2310289 Great idea! However I just tested it and it did not work -- when the setInterval enters a new function, `imgtemp` gets reset. Note that `imgtemp` is a global variable. Help :(

Answer (score 0):

It is because loadAll becomes async and returns before anything is loaded so when you call start the image has not been set yet. You'll need to "chain" them instead of calling them separately.

Only call loadAll() and then inside the loadAll add an event handler for loading the image which when loaded calls the start() function.

```
/* snip */
entries[z].getData(new zip.Data64URIWriter(), function(uri) {
    if (isMask) {
        imgtemp = new Image();
        imgtemp.onload = function(event) {
            start(); /* <--- HERE  */
        }
        imgtemp.src = uri;
    }
    else {
/* snip */
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I don't want to load start() once imgtemp is loaded, because the mask image may not be the only image.

Comment: @ihsoyih just count the number of images to load instead and when you have the total number then call start :)